# dynaically add checkboxes in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
 <div class="field row">
   <div class="span2">{{field.field_title|underscoreless}}:</div>
     <div class="span4">
        <div ng-repeat="option in field.field_options" class="row-fluid">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="{{option.option_value}}" name="{{field.field_title}}[]" id="{{field.field_title}}" ng-required="field.field_required" ng-model="field.field_value" ng-disabled="field.field_disabled"/>
            &nbsp;<span ng-bind="option.option_title"></span>
          </label>
       </div>
         <span class="required-error" ng-show="field.field_required && !field.field_value">* required</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is my anugular js code.. I want to add checkboxes dynamically and it added well. but the problem is when i select one checkbox other one also gets checked.. I dont know what to do ? Any help or suggestion?

Comment: Can you make JS Fiddle for it so that i can track exact problem

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have

```
ng-model="field.field_value"
```

means one model for all checkboxes. You have to make that model dynamic too.

Soluton -

```
ng-model="field[field_value]"
```

Comment: Please make a plunker its should work maybe you doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Like already pointed out, you are binding each checkbox to the same model, which results in checking all at once when checking one (click updates model => this triggers updating the view again, checking all boxes).
Try binding the option values to an array like this:

```
ng-model="field.value[option.value]"
```

The whole template code:

```
<div class="field row">
   <div class="span2">{{field.title}}:</div>
     <div class="span4">
        <div ng-repeat="option in field.options" class="row-fluid">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="{{option.value}}" name="{{field.title}}[]" id="{{field.title}}" ng-required="field.required" ng-model="field.value[option.value]" ng-disabled="field.disabled"/>
            &nbsp;<span ng-bind="option.title"></span>
          </label>
       </div>
         <span class="required-error" ng-show="field.required && !field.value">* required</span>
    </div>
    <pre>{{field.value}}</pre>
</div>
```

I also changed the property names without the redundancies (field.field_value => field.value and so on). In the controller:

```
$scope.field = {
  title:'Test Field',
  options:[
    {
      value: 'A',
      title: 'Option A'
    },
    {
      value: 'B',
      title:'Option B'

    },
    {
      value: 'C',
      title: 'Option C'
    }]
}
```

field.value then has values like

```
{"A":false,"B":false,"C":true}
```

Have a look at this plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/4qiUUyYCPsmvkaOEdHTk?p=preview

Answer (score -1):

It's because all checkboxes get the same id when you do `id="{{field.field_title}}"`. Change it to something like `option.id` instead.

And you're also binding them all to `ng-model="field.field_value"`, it should be `ng-model="option.value"` (or what ever property is correct for your data in option)

Comment: if i remove id attribute then also same thing is happen.. but if i remove ng-model then it work fine.. but i want to add number of checkboxs when i click add more button. and also i need ng-model attr.

Comment: The id and ng-model-value needs to be unique for each checkbox. If the ng-model is bound to the same scope-value, all the checkboxes will change when you click one of them.
`<input type="checkbox" ng-model="box1" />`

`<input type="checkbox" ng-model="box2" />`